# Allow new row in janus gridex row positioning

Tags: row, janus, gridex

I have a button that allows me to insert a new row in a Janus GridEx by setting the parameter `AllowAddNew` to true.

the new row is added to the bottom.

The problem that I faced is that when I have many rows so there is the scroll bar I am not able to make the focus on that row, even if I set the cursor to the last row and set the ensure visible parameter to true.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your row addition add the following code:

```
        if (grdEx.RowCount > 0)
            grdEx.Row = grid.RowCount - 1;
```